# Two Cluster each with 12 nodes- Cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, cluster-computing, pelops

I have started working on a project in which I am using `Cassandra database`.

Our production DBA's have setup `two cluster` and each cluster will have `12 nodes`.

I will be using `Pelops client` to read the data from Cassandra database. Now I am thinking what's the best way to create `Cluster` class using `Pelops client` like how many nodes I should add to `Pelops` while creating cluster?

My understanding was to create the cluster using `pelops client` with all the `24 nodes` as I will be having two cluster each with 12 nodes? This is the right approach?

**If not, then how we decide what nodes (from each cluster) I should add while creating the cluster using Pelops client?**

```
String[] nodes = what nodes I should use from two clusters? And how many nodes I should add?; 

int port = cfg.getInt("cassandra.port"); 

boolean dynamicND = true; // dynamic node discovery 

Config casconf = new Config(port, true, 0); 

Cluster cluster = new Cluster(nodes, casconf, dynamicND); 

Pelops.addPool(Const.CASSANDRA_POOL, cluster, Const.CASSANDRA_KS);
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to better explain the comment in the other post. My tip is to give pelops just the seeds of each cluster. Assuming you have 2 seeds for each cluster, I'd use these 4 nodes to create my pool.

You are using Pelops -- from Dominic Williams (Pelops creator) documentation:

*To create a pool, you need to specify a name, a list of known contact nodes (**the library can automatically detect further nodes in the cluster**, but see notes at the end), the network port that the nodes are listening on, and a policy which controls things like the number of connections in your pool.* -- so it's not necessary passing the whole nodes list.

From Cassandra documentation:

*Cassandra nodes exchange information about one another using a mechanism called Gossip, **but to get the ball rolling a newly started node needs to know of at least one other, this is called a Seed. It's customary to pick a small number of relatively stable nodes to serve as your seeds**, but there is no hard-and-fast rule here*

I'm in production with Pelops from 3 years (started with Cassandra 0.6 now 1.0.6) and the approach of using just seeds as list of nodes ... works fine!

couple of tips:

1 : if you are worried about connections and ring health you can write a class that make "random queries" using EACH_QUORUM CL to check connections -- and a class that uses the Nodetool java classes to check the health of the ring

2 : if you perform deletes in cassandra remember the importance of nodetool repair (http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Repairing_missing_or_inconsistent_data)

Regards,
Carlo